# cakePHP returning duplicate records

Tags: php, cakephp

For some reason cakePHP is giving me 2 copies of one result. Can anyone tell me why and how to fix it? Right now it's not a big deal, but once I get multiple playgroups for a single player, then the file download size increases.

Here's the model code:

```
        $this->recursive = -1;
        return $this->find('all', array(
            'order' => array(
                'PlaygroupActivity.timestamp DESC'
            ), 
            'limit' => $limit, 
            'joins' => array(
                array(
                    'table' => 'playgroup_players', 
                    'alias' => 'PlaygroupPlayers', 
                    'type' => 'inner', 
                    'foreignKey' => false, 
                    'conditions'=> array('PlaygroupPlayers.playgroup_id = Playgroup.id', 'PlaygroupPlayers.player_id'=>$id) 
                ),
                array(
                    'table' => 'playgroup_activities', 
                    'alias' => 'PlaygroupActivity', 
                    'type' => 'inner', 
                    'foreignKey' => false, 
                    'conditions'=> array('PlaygroupActivity.playgroup_id = Playgroup.id') 
                )
            ),
            'contain'=> array('PlaygroupActivity')
        ));
```

And the result:

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "Playgroup":{
            "id":"3",
            "name":"South Florida Redemption",
            "email":null,
            "email_username":null,
            "email_password":null,
            "tag":null,
            "description":null,
            "avatar_url":null,
            "city":null,
            "state":null
         },
         "PlaygroupActivity":[
            {
               "id":"3",
               "text":"FINAL RESULTS OF THE FLORIDA STATE TOURNAMENT ",
               "timestamp":"2011-11-02 00:13:33",
               "playgroup_id":"3",
               "timeSince":"1320210813000"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Playgroup":{
            "id":"2",
            "name":"Redemption Springfield",
            "email":null,
            "email_username":null,
            "email_password":null,
            "tag":null,
            "description":null,
            "avatar_url":null,
            "city":null,
            "state":null
         },
         "PlaygroupActivity":[
            {
               "id":"2",
               "text":"Due to bad weather, our Redemption meet today will be canceled.",
               "timestamp":"2011-02-01 14:16:21",
               "playgroup_id":"2",
               "timeSince":"1296591381000"
            },
            {
               "id":"1",
               "text":"Remember we have a meet Tuesday, February 1rst at the Greene County Library Station at 6:30pm.",
               "timestamp":"2011-01-28 23:01:57",
               "playgroup_id":"2",
               "timeSince":"1296277317000"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Playgroup":{
            "id":"2",
            "name":"Redemption Springfield",
            "email":null,
            "email_username":null,
            "email_password":null,
            "tag":null,
            "description":null,
            "avatar_url":null,
            "city":null,
            "state":null
         },
         "PlaygroupActivity":[
            {
               "id":"2",
               "text":"Due to bad weather, our Redemption meet today will be canceled.",
               "timestamp":"2011-02-01 14:16:21",
               "playgroup_id":"2",
               "timeSince":"1296591381000"
            },
            {
               "id":"1",
               "text":"Remember we have a meet Tuesday, February 1rst at the Greene County Library Station at 6:30pm.",
               "timestamp":"2011-01-28 23:01:57",
               "playgroup_id":"2",
               "timeSince":"1296277317000"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status":200
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With using joins - the GROUP BY sql statement worked best for me to remove multiple occurences of the same data:

```
$this->find('all', array('group' => 'Playgroup.id', 'join' => etc....));
```

Comment: Also Olegs method will work as well; I'm using a combination of the two for my joins.

Comment: do'h! can't believe I didn't think of groupBY!

Comment: Please note that, although this might work (and by "work" I mean, not result in errors) in some MySQL setups, it is not a correct query and the results are undefined. In a GROUP BY clause you need to specify all non-aggregate fields. This also means that you might not, and at some point will not, get the result that you want. Right now, if you want only one PlayGroup per Player, you need to specify which one!

Answer (score 0):

Introduce 'fields' key for find(), list all the fields required to be in returned result,  including 'DISTINCT Playgroup.id'

Answer (score 0):

For me did not work the fields adding, but for pagination add:

```
$this->paginate = array_merge_recursive($this->paginate, array('group' => '`Vehicle`.`id`'));//for duplicate removal
```