# Cakephp join in 3 tables showing duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have an application with tables carrentals, carrental_images and carrental_rates.
I am trying to do an left join to populate a result that shows the image and the price. However I am getting a car rental company showing four times. It has 4 images associated with it. How can i get only one image per rental in result?

```
$options = array(
                'joins' => array(
                    array(
                        'alias' => 'cm',  
                        'table' => 'carrental_images',                  
                        'type' => 'LEFT',
                        'conditions' => array(
                            'cm.carrental_id = Carrental.id = '
                        ),
                    ),

                    array(
                        'alias' => 'cr',  
                        'table' => 'carrental_rates',                   
                        'type' => 'LEFT',
                        'conditions' => array(
                            'cr.carrental_id = Carrental.id'                            
                        ),

                    ),                  

                ),
                'fields' => array(
                    'cm.image',
                    'cr.dailyRate',

                    'Carrental.id',
                    'Carrental.name',
                    'Carrental.carrental_url',                  
                    'lower(CONCAT("mysitem/cake/carrentals/", Carrental.carrental_url)) AS urlLink',    
                    'lower(CONCAT("mysite/cake/img/carrentals/thumbs/", cm.image)) AS imageLink'                
                ),
                'recursive' => 0,               
                'conditions' => array('cm.image_order' => 0),
                'limit' => 10
            );
        $this->set('rentals', $this->Carrental->find('all', $options));
```

Comment: I found the answer here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976793/cakephp-returning-duplicate-records

GROUP BY is the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a GROUP BY to limit to one row, however. You should consider marking photos as display thumbnails for the list so that the user can pick which pic they want to show to the viewer. This removes the need for the GROUP BY.